# Scala Regex help on UCI data set

Tags: regex, scala

Hi Guys i'm trying to parse some data in http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/20newsgroups/20_newsgroups.tar.gz using scala regex

**Heres the text that im trying to process:**

```
val inputData = ""xref: cantaloupe.srv.cs.cmu.edu alt.atheism:51121 soc.motss:139944 rec.scouting:5318
newsgroups: alt.atheism,soc.motss,rec.scouting
path: cantaloupe.srv.cs.cmu.edu!crabapple.srv.cs.cmu.edu!fs7.ece.cmu.edu!europa.eng.gtefsd.com!howland.reston.ans.net!wupost!uunet!newsgate.watson.ibm.com!yktnews.watson.ibm.com!watson!watson.ibm.com!strom
from: strom@watson.ibm.com (rob strom)
subject: re: [soc.motss, et al.] "princeton axes matching funds for boy scouts"
sender: @watson.ibm.com
message-id: <1993apr05.180116.43346@watson.ibm.com>
date: mon, 05 apr 93 18:01:16 gmt
distribution: usa
references: <c47efs.3q47@austin.ibm.com> <1993mar22.033150.17345@cbnewsl.cb.att.com> <n4hy.93apr5120934@harder.ccr-p.ida.org>
organization: ibm research
lines: 15

in article <n4hy.93apr5120934@harder.ccr-p.ida.org>, n4hy@harder.ccr-p.ida.org (bob mcgwier) writes:

|> [1] however, i hate economic terrorism and political correctness
|> worse than i hate this policy.  


|> [2] a more effective approach is to stop donating
|> to any organizating that directly or indirectly supports gay rights issues
|> until they end the boycott on funding of scouts.  

can somebody reconcile the apparent contradiction between [1] and [2]?

-- 
rob strom, strom@watson.ibm.com, (914) 784-7641
ibm research, 30 saw mill river road, p.o. box 704, yorktown heights, ny  10598"
```

**Here's the output that i need**

```
in article <n4hy.93apr5120934@harder.ccr-p.ida.org>, n4hy@harder.ccr-p.ida.org (bob mcgwier) writes:

|> [1] however, i hate economic terrorism and political correctness
|> worse than i hate this policy.  


|> [2] a more effective approach is to stop donating
|> to any organizating that directly or indirectly supports gay rights issues
|> until they end the boycott on funding of scouts.  

can somebody reconcile the apparent contradiction between [1] and [2]?
```

**Here's what i tried:**

```
val docParser = """([\\s\\S]+\\lines: \\d*)([\\s\\S]*\\n\\n)([\\s\\S]*)""".r
val docParser(metadata, content, footer) = inputText
```

But im getting the following error:

**scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@62f8fff1 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)**

**Online regex builder seems to work though:**
[image: Online regex builder seems to work]

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

I have never programmed in scala before, but from what I can see in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_regular_expressions.htm
you have to escape twice stuff like digits.

So `\d` would become `\\d` in scala and so on.

Comment: thanks! ive tried your suggestion and used """([\\s\\S]+\\lines: \\d*)([\\s\\S]*\\n\\n)([\\s\\S]*)""".r 

but doesnt seem to work also

Comment: I believe the error lies in \lines. Are you sure you wish to escape that L?

Comment: Trying this, but seems to be erroring out
 
  val docParser = """([\\s\\S]+lines: \\d*)([\\s\\S]*\\n\\n)([\\s\\S]*)""".r
  
   scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@3d650371 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)

Comment: Try again without escaping twice, maybe """ means literal string in scala. Sorry for being unable to test it; just giving you wild shots :)